# Android:Retain state of application when launch from background to foreground

Tags: android

I want to show notification of my application in the form of icon,whether it is run in background or foreground.If we launch application from notification  then I want my applications state prior to application in background.

Answer (score 0):

Android apps retain their state by default. There are a few exceptions to this, but normally its not a problem. To enable your application to do work in the background you should look into the Service class.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Simply I want to launch my application from notification should retain its state.I don't want to use service.

Comment: You will need a service to show notification. To keep the state of your activity you can use SharedPreferences

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android notification from [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)

And you can use the service if you are developing and media applicaion.

Comment: Actually,in my application,if I clicked on notification then activity get start from root and not maintaining state

Comment: then simply add some variable to get the state of activity and check that variable on Create activity. Suppose if you are using media player, set a variable true on media play in service class. then check that variable on activity create and set button icon according to that.